# Use object from Node.js / Express backend in frontend JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, frontend, backend

Noob in programming here, my question is probably fairly stupid but I've been spending a lot of time searching for a solution to no avail.

I'm coding a prototype for a simple web app. Back end uses Node.js, Express and MongoDB. I use twig to render the pages to the client. And I need to use some frontend JS.

Here is my route:

```
router.get("/game/:id", objectsController.showObjectGame)
```

Here is the controller:

```
exports.showObjectGame = (req, res) => {
objectModel.findById(req.params.id)
.exec()
.then(object => {
    res.render("objectGame.html.twig", {object: object})
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
})}
```

Then I'm able to render a page with a given object properties:

```
<h2>Title1</h2>
    <div id="property1">{{object.property1}}</div>

<h2>Title2</h2>
    <div id="property2">{{object.property2}}</div>
<h2>Title3</h2>
    <div id="property3"><img src="/images/{{object.property3}}"></div>
```

On this page, I import a JS file:

```
<script src="/javascript/objectGame.js"></script>
```

My issue is that I need to pass the object to a variable in objectGame.js, in order to execute the frontend script. For the life of me, I can't figure how to do it.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: can you describe about the structure of `objectGame.js`. is it functional, object oriented or some pattern?

Comment: objectGame.js is a very simple script that defines a variable containing a Leaflet map and displays it, plus a function that displays the coordinates of a point when you click the map.

Then, I need to add a function that will perform a quick calculation using these coordinates and some properties of the object stored in the database, and show the result to the client.

Comment: Another alternative is to create a script tag inside the `objectGame.html.twig` file. and then your object variable is still in the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think could be useful.
First we have to restructure code in `objectGame.js`. For this we can use IIFE pattern.

Here's how objectGame.js code will look like

```
 const objectGame = (function() {
  //varible initializations
  let somevar = null;
  
  function _init(objectFromServer) {
    somevar = objectFromServer;
   //other initilization code
  }

  //other functions

  return {
    init: _init,
    //other methods can be added
  }
})();
```

After importing objectGame.js `objectGame` function defined above will be available in global space and can be used like this.

```
<script src="/javascript/objectGame.js"></script>
<script>
  objectGame.init({{someObjectFromServer}});
</script>
```